# AWS SAM integration with OpenAPI - why variables are not working?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, integration, openapi

I'm trying to use OpenAPI to make documentation on lambda functions in my AWS SAM project.
This is my template.yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  SAM Template
  
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    CodeUri: nodejs/
    Architectures:
      - x86_64

Resources:
  NodeModulesLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      Description: the node_modules
      ContentUri: ./
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs18.x
      RetentionPolicy: Retain

  ZorrosFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: nodejs/handlers/zorro
      Handler: handler.lambdaHandler
      Layers:
        - !Ref NodeModulesLayer
      Events:
        MyEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /zorros
            Method: get
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
  TheGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Dev
      DefinitionUri: ./swagger.yaml
```

And this is my swagger.yaml file:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  title: "Simple API"
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /zorros:
    get:
      summary: "Get zorros"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: "aws_proxy"
        httpMethod: "GET"
        uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${ZorrosFunction.Arn}/invocations
```

When I try to make deploy via "sam deploy --guided", I get this message: "Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/zorros': Invalid lambda function"
But when I don't use variables and instead of it use the plain function Arn, the deploy is OK. So, what's wrong with my variables?